# How can I join fact tables on incremental models without loosing data?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt, dataform, incremental-build

I have two tables containing different events, Table A and Table B, both of them are partitioned tables. I need to join these two tables, however, if I filter using a timestamp, I'll lose some events due to partitioning filter.

Example - Table A:

| event_a_id | timestamp | event_b_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 2023-10-01 | b1 |
| a2 | 2023-10-01 | b2 |

Table B:

| event_b_id | timestamp | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | 2023-01-01 | lorem |
| b2 | 2023-10-01 | ipsum |

Result:

| event_a_id | timestamp | event_b_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 2023-10-01 | b1 | null |
| a2 | 2023-10-01 | b2 | ipsum |

If I filter both tables on `timestamp = "2023-10-01"` I will get event b2, but not event b1. How can I avoid this? I can't simple select the whole table, because it is huge, however, I can't publish the table with missing data.

I have tried filtering only 1 of tables, it reduces the amount of data processed, but does not solve the problem of missing information on the rows.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good write-up of your options by Tristan Handy, CEO of dbt Labs, [here](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/on-the-limits-of-incrementality/303).

To summarize, you can design for correctness or performance, but you may need to accept some tradeoffs.

Max performance would be filtering both tables on the current date, as you describe:

```sql
select a.id, a.timestamp, a.event_b_id, b.text
from a
left join b 
    on a.event_b_id = b.id
    {% if is_incremental() %}
    and b.timestamp >= (select max(timestamp) from {{ this }})
    {% endif %}
{% if is_incremental() %}
where a.timestamp >= (select max(timestamp) from {{ this }})
{% endif %}
```

Max correctness would be only filtering table A:

```sql
select a.id, a.timestamp, a.event_b_id, b.text
from a
left join b 
    on a.event_b_id = b.id
{% if is_incremental() %}
where a.timestamp >= (select max(timestamp) from {{ this }})
{% endif %}
```

A compromise solution might include creating a window for late-arriving data in table A. For example, join rows in B if they were recorded less than 30 days before A:

```sql
select a.id, a.timestamp, a.event_b_id, b.text
from a
left join b 
    on a.event_b_id = b.id
    {% if is_incremental() %}
    and b.timestamp >= (
        select date_sub(max(timestamp), interval '30 days')
        from {{ this }}
    )
    {% endif %}
{% if is_incremental() %}
where a.timestamp >= (select max(timestamp) from {{ this }})
{% endif %}
```

(If your data in B arrives late, you would flip this logic around; you could also include a range on both tables A and B).